# Error while Upgrading kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, requirejs, upgrade

We have a custom JavaScript framework. Requirejs( 2.1.5), jQuery(v1.10.2), kendo(v2014.1.318), Bootstrap and moment js files are included in that framework.

We are trying to upgrade kendo to latest version(v2017.2.621). Please let us know approach for the same.

Comment: Please specify exactly what kind of an error you are receiving and also tell us what steps you took to perform the upgrade.

Comment: The custom JS framework is a js file. All the contents of jQuery, Kendo and other libraries copied into the framework js file. So we have removed the contents of previous versions and added the latest version of libraries in the framework js file.

Comment: We are getting multiple errors as below.
• Object doesn't support property or method 'angular'(In Kendo dropdown)
• Unable to get property 'click.kendoAutoComplete' of undefined or null reference.
• Unable to get property of kendo.UI kendo.ui.Select, 
• Unable to get property of  Kendo.UI.List 
• Kendo.UIDataBoundWidget  undefined(In Kendo Grid)